# Use the first day of the month as 1(integer)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build my **first app using flutter** framework. The app is about my "End of Year Challenge". It started from `1st Sept 2019` and will last till the end of this year.

What I'm trying to achieve is - I want to display the current day number of the challenge period. eg: 1st Sept is `Day 1`, `30th Sept` is `Day 30` and `1st Oct` is `Day 31` and so on.

I'm trying to get the first day of Sept and assign it to 1. Then using a loop I want the app to update the day to the current day. The loop will stop once the current day equals to `122` (as this would be the last day of the challenge)

Here's the screenshot of the UI

[image: Screenshot of the app]

```
final firstSeptember = DateTime.utc(2019, DateTime.september, 1);
static const totalNumberOfDays = 122;

int noOfDay(){
    int dayOne = firstSeptember.day; // I'm just trying codes, IDK the actual code/business logic
    return dayOne;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In function you'd use

```
int noOfDay(){
  var todayDate = DateTime.now();
  final firstSeptember = DateTime.utc(2019, DateTime.september, 1);
  var difference = todayDate.difference(firstSeptember);
  return difference.inDays + 1;
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

Get today's date

```
var todayDate = DateTime.now();
```

You already have start date which is

```
final firstSeptember = DateTime.utc(2019, DateTime.september, 1);
```

All you need to do is subtraction.

```
var difference = todayDate.difference(firstSeptember);
int daysCompleted = difference.inDays + 1;
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot for adding the explanation. @CopsOnRoad

Comment: I'm facing a minor bug with the code. `var difference` is giving me the difference in utc. I've added `toLocal()` on `todayDate` and `firstSeptember`, but still the difference is of 5:30 hrs. How can I get the local time zone difference? @CopsOnRoad

Comment: Can you edit your question with more some figures and detail? I'll be happy to assist.

Comment: `var todayDate = DateTime.now();` is returning date in IST, whereas `final firstSeptember = DateTime.utc(2019, 09, 01);` is returning date in UTC (I know it's behaving normally). Now, `var difference = todayDate.difference(firstSeptember);` is also returning date in UTC but I want it to return IST. **Because in my app, the day changes at 5:30 am while it should have already changed at 12:00 am.** BTW I'm from India. UTC is 5:30 hr behind IST. @CopsOnRoad

Comment: @ManishPaul That's because you are using `DateTime.utc(2019, 09, 01)`, simply remove utc and use `DateTime(2019, 09, 01)`.

Comment: Thanks again mate. Can you suggest me how to solve these problems on my own? I'm finding difficult to understand the documentation. Please guide me as to how can I approach my problems through documentation. @CopsOnRoad

Comment: @ManishPaul You can watch YouTube tutorials or enrol in a course on Udacity/Udemy.